# Multiple caller id in RingCentral for different branch

Tags: ringcentral

We want to have multiple caller IDs. I was wondering if we can configure a multiple Caller IDs for RingCentral. Our organization has 3 division, a main branch and 2 subsidiary located in different area. So if caller id is set to main branch, we also want to have the numbers associated with 2 subsidiary branch to reflect that branch's name on the caller ID.

Currently all the topic I found in online says it shows main parent branch number to set as Caller ID.
I searched all the net but haven't got an answer.
Can anyone suggest how can I have different Caller ID using one Ring Central account for different branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to activate multi-site and allocate each of the numbers you wish to reflect with a specific ***CNAM*** tied to that site.
For "Parent branch" you would set "Parent branch name" as the Caller ID Name, "branch1" would set "branch1 name" as the Caller ID Name and so on.

Then you would then associate users/DIDs to specific sites that need to make calls using a different ***CNAM***.
see the same solution given for reference for same problem here:  https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/27583/multiple-caller-id-company-names.html